# HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error using visual studio 2013

Tags: browser, visual-studio-2013, iis-8

I am using visual studio 2013. I am trying to run a web app on my browser and I get the following error.

[image]

I have searched this forum but is not working. I was running the same web app yesterday and it worked fine.Today it does not.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 6):

I too faced this problem when my Windows was upgraded.
Doing this fixed the issue on my computer. Also note that you have to select the Server node on the left side panel. (NOT a web site).
Follow the instructions in the screenshots and then
Uncheck the www server checkbox.
Restart the IIS and it worked on my machine!

[image: IIS settings]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the correct solution, rather than deleting the config on individual sites. I ran into this issue migrating a site from IIS 7 to a new IIS 10 server.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing similar issue from last 2-3 days. I am using VS2013 professional for building MVC application. All of sudden, any web application created on VS2013 started giving this kind of error. I tried reinstalling IIS, VS2013; but it does not worked for me.

During event logs checks, I found this error message-

*"FailedRequestTracing module detected invalid configuration on path 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST'. Trace provider or tracing area name 'WWW Server' is not recognized. Check the  section for currently supported list or providers and areas. No logs will be generated until this condition is corrected. The problem happened at least 1 times in the last 5 minutes. The data is the error."*

In applicationhost.config file, I did found below tag-

```
<add provider="WWW Server" areas="Authentication,Security,Filter,StaticFile,CGI,Compression,Cache,RequestNotifications,Module,FastCGI,WebSocket,Rewrite,RequestRouting,iisnode" verbosity="Verbose" />
```

I removed this tag from applicationhost.config file located under C:\Users\\My Documents\IISExpress\config path on windows 7 machine.

Now my all application started running fine from VS2013 with IISexpress.

See if this helps.

Cheers

Sanket

Comment: I'm running into this issue; it's just a website that I created under IIS to handle url rewriting to the tomcat server I'm running locally for development.   So far I haven't found any reason for it to suddenly stop working with this error (I've made no changes that I'm aware of)