# IIS 7.5 Tracing area "...." is not recognized - HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-7.5, iis-express

Everything was working fine and all of a sudden I started getting the following error for all my web projects and websites. One thing is for sure that this is IIS issue since the compiler is not even reach the code.

Error Message:

HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error

Tracing area "Authentication,Security,Filter,StaticFile,CGI,Compression,Cache,RequestNotifications,Module,FastCGI,WebSocket,Rewrite,RequestRouting,iisnode" is not recognized

[image]

I've already tried following things one by one but no luck:

1. Re-install Tracing - 'Turn Windows features on or off',
2. Re-install IIS,
3. aspnet_regiis -i (also tried with -u),
4. Removed ISAPI .DLL

Windows Features:

[image]

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 to build a web project (asp.net C#).

I would really appreciate any help/information on this Issue.

Comment: I learned that IIS was working fine and the problem was with the VS debugging environment. My VS upgrade was due and after the upgrade (2013 to 2015), the issue was resolved. I still don't know the exact root cause of the problem but I'm guessing it was caused by conflicts in DLLs (dll hell).

Answer (score 7):

I removed below tag from applicationhost.config file located under C:\Users\Sanket\My Documents\IISExpress\config path on windows 7 machine.

```
<add provider="WWW Server" areas="Authentication,Security,Filter,StaticFile,CGI,Compression,Cache,RequestNotifications,Module,FastCGI,WebSocket,Rewrite,RequestRouting,iisnode" verbosity="Verbose" />
```

See if this helps.

Comment: Great solution. Worked well for me.

Answer (score 3):

Sanket's suggestion works, but for me what was missing was

```
<add name="RequestRouting" value="2048" />
```

a few lines above in the applicationhost.config file, where all areas are defined. Adding this fixed it.
Btw. using VS2015 also fixes the problem without editing the .config file.

Comment: for me adding <add name="RequestRouting" value="1024" /> worked to fix the problem.  The problem occurred after an upgrade from Win Server 2012R2 to 2019 (IIS 8.5 -> 10)

Answer (score 2):

From Richard Marr's Blog [here](https://blogs.iis.net/richma/missing-failed-request-tracing-freb-trace-areas), following solutions are listed and second solution worked for me.

1. Using Programs and Features find the Extension that is missing  trace areas, right click select REPAIR.
2. Manually add the trace areas to the Applicationhost.config file as shown below. Remember to add in the "WWW Server" xml Node.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you have all modules listed in error message installed? You can download extensions here: (link for rewrite module) http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

Comment: Thanks for your input Kamil but I resolved this issue by installing VS 2015. I thing the problem was with some DLLs getting dead locked.

Answer (score 0):

To add to [Sanket's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37675163/7311767):

In case you are not using IIS Express, in

```
C:\Inetpub\Wwwroot\Web.Config
```

Delete the line with:

```
"Authentication,Security,Filter,StaticFile,CGI,Compression,Cache,RequestNotifications,Module,FastCGI,WebSocket,Rewrite,RequestRouting,iisnode" verbosity="Verbose"
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was getting the error in IIS (NOT IIS express). I answered this question here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51717759/2817987